# How to find failed insert statements from bulk inserts in SQL *PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, sqlplus, bulkinsert

I have been trying to insert nearly 10K rows in my table through SQL *PLUS. However, when I count in SQL DEVELOPER missing nearly 10 rows out of 10K rows.

How to find which rows are failed to insert into table?

I have prepared insert script in Excel and copying 10K rows from Excel and pasting into SQL *PLUS. This process is completing within 5 min but missing some rows.

Please help me to find those missing rows.

Comment: Aren't you getting errors when your insert fails?

Comment: spool the sqlplus' output it into a file and grep  for errors in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague, and I'm guessing at the exact form of your script, so my answer tries to offer you some options without being precise.

You could try something like this:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE COMMIT
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( 'a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1');
.
.
```

This will cause the script to stop at the first error, but with the COMMIT it will enable you to see how far you got (assuming there is some logical order in insert order).

This is a quick and dirty way to hone in on the errors.

A second way, is to have PROMPTs interspersed to show what values are being inserted to assist with debug:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
PROMPT INSERTING a, b, c
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( 'a', 'b', 'c');
PROMPT INSERTING a1, b1, c1
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1');
.
.
```

Another idea, a little more involved. Assuming you are using EXCEL to generate the INSERT statements you could generate them as calls to a pr_insert procedure, and then have logic in the procedure to trap and flag up the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_insert
   ( p1 IN t1.c1%TYPE,
     p2 IN t1.c2%TYPE,
     p3 IN t1.c3%TYPE ) AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ( p1, p2, p3 );
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20001, 'Error on : ' || p1 || ',' || p2 || 'p3 );
END ;
/
```

The following pr_insert calls can be generated in you Excel:

```
BEGIN
  pr_insert ( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
  pr_insert ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' );
  pr_insert ( 'a2', 'b2', 'c2' );
.
.
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much @TenG, its very helpful and its perfect answer. the end part was a bit confusing, if possible can u explain that? and yes, i am preparing insert scripts in Excel.

Comment: Re the "end part", create the stored procedure pr_insert to accept the insert values as parameters, and rasie an exception printing the values if the insert fails. Then in your Excel, instead of generating the "INSERT..." statements generate the "pr_insert(..." statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is one way to find missing rows , mostly table will have one primary key or make primary key using sequence ... try to load primary key alone in another table say lookup table  .... Then make query between actual loaded table and lookup table to find missing rows

create table temp
( id number,
sal number)

begin 
insert into temp values (1,100);
insert into temp values (2,200);
insert into temp values (3,300);
insert into temp values (5,400);
end;

select * from temp;

create table lookup
(id number);

begin 
insert into lookup values(1);
insert into lookup values(2);
insert into lookup values(3);
insert into lookup values(4);
insert into lookup values(5);
end;

select * from lookup;

select * from lookup where id not in ( select id from temp);
```